# How to block second onClick event firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've built some functions, that fires ajax events on click events with jquery, the problem is, that when you click fast enough - event gets fired two times and this should not happen :). I was trying to avoid this with adding flag variable, but when you are really fast it just doesn't work. Here is example of my function:

```
action_flag = 0;

$('#available_clicks').delegate('.available_click', "click", function(ev)
{
    if(action_flag==1)
    { 
        ev.stopPropagation();
        return;
    }
    action_flag=1;
    somefunction();
});
```

At the end of somefunction is action_flag=0 instruction. 
Can you provide me some solution, which will prevent from double firing somefunction when user clicks fast enough? : )

**EDIT:**

Now i'm doing it that way:

```
$('#available_clicks').delegate('.available_click', "click", function(ev)
{
   $("#available_clicks").on("click", ".available_click",somefunction())); 
   $("#available_clicks").off("click", ".available_click");
});
```

But it gets an error after second click : /

Comment: Your posted code is completely synchronous, this shouldn't happen.

Comment: 99.8% probability that you oversimplified the snippet removing the faulty code. Your code works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/QDX9P/

Comment: See this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873019/is-there-any-way-to-delegate-the-event-one-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `.one()` `jQuery` function that will help you.

> **Description:** Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element.

**OR**

You can use `.off();`

> **Description:** Remove an event handler.

**EDIT**

```
$('#available_clicks').on("click",'.available_click', function(ev)
{
   $("body").off("click", ".available_click");
});
```

Comment: Removing and re-attaching the event handler constantly isn't much better than doing your own handling.

Comment: How to attach .one() to delegate?

Comment: @pawel you need to use it as `$("#DOM").one("click",`

Comment: @pawel for delegate you can use `.off` too

Comment: @DipeshParmar Thank you, but I need to delegate events into my objects,because they dont exist at first, I'm loading them with ajax later.

Comment: @pawel as i said, you can use `.off` for delegate...see http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: @DipeshParmar Could you look at my 1st post edit?

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable the button (this being the first statement in the function) and in the success of the ajax call, you can enable it again it.