# Jquery off event from a single element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying too take off the event from only `this` element , if I try `$(this).off('event');` they take off event from all elements and `$(this).off('click');` don't work

```
$(document).on('click', '.text', function (event) {
    var box = "<div class = 'box'></div>";
    $(box).insertAfter("#body");
    $(this).off('event');
});
```

Comment: $(this).off(event); *

Comment: If you have to use event delegation, then consider to remove class `.text` from current element. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512253/remove-jquery-delegated-event-handler-on-specific-object

Comment: ohhh, i understand the logic now, i need to remove the class or id then if i want to let user click again in this element i just put the class or id back

Comment: BTW, you also have an option to namespace an event `$( element ).on( 'click.myNamespace', {})` and turn it off using `$( element ).on( '.myNamespace'` (But the use of classes as suggested is much better)

Comment: If you don't have to use event delegation, you can do something like this:
http://jsbin.com/fewida/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).on('click', '.text', myEventHandler);

function myEventHandler(e){
  $(this).off('click', myEventHandler);
  var box = "<div class = 'box'></div>";
  $(box).insertAfter("#body");
}
```