# jQuery .one() doesn't fire once per-element, but only once

Tags: jquery

I am currently struggling with jQuery `.one()`. The documentation states

> The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

If I have three inputs and do something like `$(document).one("click", "input", function () { ... }` as in https://jsfiddle.net/rr49ryyo/, I expect that the event is fired 3 times if I click on all 3 inputs, but in fact, it is only fired once in total and not once per element. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

`.one` behaves as expected if I attach the handler via `$("input").one("click", function () { ... }` but my problem is that I need to respond to events fired by dynamically added inputs. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you use `$(document).one(...)` it actually sets a single listener on document which is triggered when a descendant `input` element is the target of an event and is removed after being fired once.

With `$('input').one(...)` it sets a listener on each input element, each of which is removed when fired.

Edit: You can get around this by seeing @Phil's comment link to [Is there any way to delegate the event one in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873019/is-there-any-way-to-delegate-the-event-one-in-jquery)

Solution:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/6873265/1059070
>
> ```
> $('#container').delegate('.children', 'click', function() {
>   if($(this).data('clicked')) {
>       return;
>   }
>
>   // ... your code here ...
>
>
>   $(this).data('clicked', true);
>
> });
> ```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I just referenced the other answer directly.